# Require assistance is building a method that returns the earliest date value

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring a method for a legacy codebase I have taken over for.
The method takes in an object of forecasted dates.
When the forecasted date is within a count of 30, 40 or 60 it should return the earliest time by being converted using the getTime() method.

This currently returns the earliest date of the objects that it receives, the issue is that it only does a comparison with 2 dates, it returns star date, and only one of the 2 values in runout dates instead of comparing all 3 and returning the the lowest .getTime() value

Below is the method that returns the earliest date

```js
const getEarliestRunout = (runout_dates = {}, dm1_type = '') => {
     try{
        const cur_year = new Date().getFullYear();

        const non_priority_sticker = dm1_type == cur_year + 1 || dm1_type == cur_year ? 'dm1' : 'dm2';
    
        return Object.entries(runout_dates).reduce((earliest,obj) => {            
            const key = obj[0].split('_')[0];

            const value = obj[1];
            
            if(value[`under_${env.STICKER_THRESH[0]}`] && key != non_priority_sticker) {
                return new Date(value[`under_${env.STICKER_THRESH[0]}`]).getTime() < earliest.val ? {val: new Date(value[`under_${env.STICKER_THRESH[0]}`]).getTime(), date: value[`under_${env.STICKER_THRESH[0]}`]} : {...earliest}
            }
            return earliest
        },{val: Infinity, date:''})
    }catch(e){
        console.error(`ERROR :: util.getEarliestRunout: ${e} - ${new Date()}`);
        return {val: Infinity, date: ''}
    }
}
```

Below is the variable used to call the method in use

```js
const earliest_runout = getEarliestRunout({
 dm1_runouts: value.dm1_type == priority_sticker ? priorityRunouts : nonPriorityRunouts,
 dm2_runouts: value.dm2_type == priority_sticker ? priorityRunouts : nonPriorityRunouts,
 star_runouts: starRunouts
},value.dm1_type);
```

I was expecting the method to compare all dates but it is only comparing 2. I am pretty sure that it is how I am calling the method, but I am not sure. I am reaching out to ask to get further with this, as I am stumped as how to get the result I am looking for.

I am sure I can reword this to be more clear, but just to reiterate. This method takes in date values ( in my use case only 3 dates) and return the earliest date using Math.min and getTime(). The result I am receiving is its returning all date values but only comparing the star value and either or of the dm1_runout or dm2_runout. It stays consistent in the comparison is returning only one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the answer for my issue. I created a date array, ran each method through Math.min method and pushed each value into the date array and then sorted the array to filter NaN with an empty string and to only return the lowest value from Math.min that matched for each loop through the array for each object.